# Changing the location on disk where XP Mode VHD file is stored

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

Using Windows 7 x64, my boot disk is an SSD. I'd like to reserve it for Windows 7 programs, and locate the XP Mode VHD on a second standard HD.  Can that be done?  After creating XP Mode, can I shut it down, relocate it, and then edit the **pathname** node in "Windows XP Mode.vmc"?

```
<ide_controller id="0">
 <location id="0">
   <drive_type type="integer">1</drive_type>
 <pathname>
  <absolute type="string">**C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Virtual PC\Virtual Machines\Windows XP Mode.vhd**</absolute>
<relative type="string">.\Windows XP Mode.vhd</relative>
</pathname>
<undo_pathname>
   <absolute type="string" />
    <relative type="string" />
</undo_pathname>
</location>
```

Answer (score 2):

> After creating XP Mode, can I shut it down, relocate it, and then edit
>   the pathname node in "Windows XP Mode.vmc"?

I'd say, just try it. If it doesn't work, revert the changes and create a symlink, that should always work.

Comment: +1:IMO, the symlink is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

By rule of thumb, the base VHD file located in Program Files cannot, unfortunately, be moved or renamed. If you do attempt to do this, XP Mode will cease functioning.

To move the files under the C drive to an alternate location you would first boot up in to XP Mode.

Instead of saving the virtual machine (VM), you want to shut it down. (Be sure to change the close settings to prompt the user for close action.)

When closing the VM you will want to choose shutdown. This will remove the .VSV file. Do not manually delete the .VSV file, as it contains unsaved data within the VM.

Now, you can move the VHD located in the following path: `C:\Users\[yourusernamehere]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Virtual PC\Virtual Machines\Windows XP Mode.vhd` to your desired location.

Open XP mode settings, navigate to Hard Disk 1 settings, and repoint the hard disk to the new location of your VHD file. You should now be able to boot the VM as you did previously.

Comment: Please avoid advertising other communities here.